# Decrease size of / mask / move offscreen CGRect

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, core-graphics, cgrect

I am trying to create an app in xcode that will make a CGRect, tie the shape to a timer and then to create the appearance that the shape is slowly draining from the bottom of the screen (off screen), similar to if it were a liquid in a container with a hole in the bottom or the top of an hourglass.  I found an example project on github that creates a path and fills in an arc with a color over a circle called SRCountdownTimer, but I can't figure out the best way to achieve what I want.  I have no problem creating a class that will create the fullscreen CGRect, and fill it in with color and also tying it to a countdown timer using elapsedTime / totalTime.  But as far as creating the illusion of the rectangle draining, I'm kind of lost.  Any specific help or suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553552/i-want-to-draw-custom-shape-like-apple-shape-on-uiview Imagine that the line dividing the colors in the middle of the apple is horizontal and slowly moves down. Is that the sort of thing you're talking about?

Comment: Or maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883087/341994 Imagine if the teardrop were a _mask_ and the direction were reversed: only the "liquid" inside would be visible, and it would funnel out.