# Swift/ios wave fill animation inside custom layer/shape

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to achieve a fill animation similar to the GIF below but inside a non circular boundary similar to the second image. Can this be done over a UIImage of just the drop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883087/341994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could do that with a CAShapeLayer where you animate the path that draws the shape. You'd then add a mask layer to the shape layer that masks it to the shape of the drop, (which would be another shape layer in the shape of your drop.)

You should be able to get the shape of the wave with a single cubic bezier curve, as wide as the widest part of the area you're filling. You'd create a closed shape that was your wave curve, then the sides and bottom of a rectangle to create a closed shape.

For the wave animation I would suggest a closed UIBezierPath that is 3 sides of a rectangle, followed by a cubic bezier curve who's start and end where on the top corners of your rectangle, and the middle two control points were at 1/4 and 3/4 of the way along the rectangle in the X dimension. Make one of those control points above the top line of your box, and the other below the top line. The animation would just be switching the Y positions of the 2 middle control points of the bezier curve.

Here is what the shape looks like in Photoshop:

[image]

Make that bezier path wider than your drop shape, so the ends of the top curve that don't move are out of view.

You'd install the CGPath of that bezier path into a CAShapeLayer. You'd then add a repeating, auto-reversing CABasicAnimation to the shape layer that would swap the Y positions of the two middle control points of the top curve, so the wave peaks and troughs would switch.

Next, you'd create a second CAShapeLayer that would contain a closed drop shape, and install the drop shape layer as a mask on the wave layer.

Finally, as you change your slider, you'd shift the Y position of your entire wave shape layer up and down.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, will have to give it a try soon. Will update shortly

Comment: Thanks Duncan, 
Just started work on it. Thanks for the detailed breakdown.